# Pig - Not loading the data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

input data:

```
(10,1,{(2,3),(4,6)})
(10,3,{(2,3),(4,6)})
(10,6,{(2,3),(4,6),(5,7)})
```

Pig query:

> x= load '/data.txt' as (d1:int, d2:int, B:bag{T:tuple(t1:int,
>   t2:int)});

But I am getting the Output like:

```
(,,)
(,,)
(,,)
(,,)
```

I am not sure where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is enclosed by braces which means it's a tuple. You have to define a outer structure to consider the data as a tuple and then place your fields.

Here is what you need:

```
x= load '/data.txt' as (a:tuple(d1:int, d2:int, B:bag{T:tuple(t1:int, t2:int)}));
```